# Java swing keybinding

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, action, key-bindings

This is in the constructor of a JPanel but it does not print anything when I press "h".  If more code is needed, I can provide it.  Thank you!

```
String hide = "hide";
    this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('h'), hide);
    this.getActionMap().put(hide, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("HIDDEN");
            if (isHidden){
                slide.setVisible(true);
            }else{
                slide.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: BTW you can only use `slide.setVisible(isHidden);` , you can use `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)' if i don't mistake or when ancestor

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  slide.setVisible(true/false) works pretty well to my knowledge.

Comment: You can the if/else statement with a single line of code that does the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  How do I tell the boolean to switch to its opposite value without an if/else?

Comment: To toggle the state you could use: `slide.setVisible( ! slide.isVisible() );`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.getInputMap()....
```

You are trying to add the bindings to the default InputMap, which is the InputMap when the component has focus. By default a JPanel does not have focus.

You should try using one of the other InputMaps by using the `getInputMap(int)` method. Or you will need to make the panel focusable and give it focus.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information on the proper variables to use to specify the desired InputMap.

Comment: Thank you!  WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW worked pretty well.  Is there something I can replace that with so that it'll work even when the window is not focused?  My application is set to be always on top so it will always be visible but not necessarily in focus.  Thanks!

Comment: No. Swing only responds to events when it has focus.

Comment: Not that I know of. It is not good for an application to take over your screen.